# コロンのある行にsyntax errorが出る

Tags: python, python3

数日前にプログラミングを始めました初心者です。

このコーディングをすると、コロンにマーカーが現れて syntax error が表示されます。「self-taught programmer」という本で学んでいて、もちろん見本コードと見比べてデバッグを試みたのですがそれでも分かりませんでした。

このコードは単語当てゲームです。事前に設定された単語を当てるために何度もアルファベットを入力します。しかし間違えるたびにうんちがぶら下げられた絵が姿を表します。うんちがぶら下げられてしまうか、正しい単語を導くかの高度な頭脳戦です。

```
def hangshit(word):
    print("YOU WANNA HANG A SHIT!")
    wrong=0
    stage=["",
           "______        ",
           "|     |       ",
           "|     |       ",
           "|     |       ",
           "|    ノヽ      ",
           "|  （＿　 ）    ",
           "| （＿　 　 ）  ",
           "|（＿＿＿＿＿ ） ",
           "|　 　　　　　　 "
           ]
    list_shit=list(word)
    board_shit=["__"]*len(word)

    while wrong<len(stage)-1:
        print("\n")
        guess=input("ENTER,you shit")
        if guess in list_shit:
            print("YOU GOOD BOY")
            ana= list_shit.index(guess)
            board_shit[ana]=guess
            list_shit[ana]="$$$$$"
        else:
            print("YOU SHIT")
            wrong +=1
        print(" ".join(boad.shit))
        e= wrong+1
        print("\n".join(stage[:e])
       if "__" not in board_shit:
              print("You win!")
              print(" ".join(board_shit))
              win=True
              break
    if not win:
        print("\n".join(stage[:wrong+1])
        print("YOU NOTHING BUT SHIT, here is true SHIT! {}".format(word)

hangshit("dog")
```

Comment: Syntax Error にも色々なケースがあるので、どんなエラーメッセージが出たのかも質問文に含めておくとより親切だと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すぐ上の行の括弧が閉じられていません。

```
print("\n".join(stage[:e])
```

正しくはこうです。

```
print("\n".join(stage[:e]))
```

Comment: 初めまして。ご回答ありがとうございます。IDLEという開発環境でやっているのですが、エラーメッセージにはSyntax Error としか出てきていませんでした。どこかでエラーの詳細を見る方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、文の途中でコメントを送信してしまいました。続きです。＞＞＞確か、コードブロックの中に指示を書き込みたいときにインデントを揃えるのですよね。IDLEではエンターを押すだけで改行した文はそのコードブロックに含まれるようになると思っていたので、自分でインデントを4回入力しなければならないと初めて知りました。ありがとうございます。しかしご指摘の通りに、インデントを揃えても同様のSyntax Error が表示されました。もし他にも可能性があればご指摘お願いします。

Comment: すいません、今回のエラーが出る根本の原因を見誤っていたので内容を書き直しました。（インデントについてもエラーが出ていたと思いますが、それとは別の間違いがあることに気付いてませんでした。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、たくさんのかっこ閉じ漏れがありました。全て修正したら動きました。スカッとしました、ありがとうございました。